# Call external code from JMeter webdriver sampler

Tags: jmeter, webdriver

I am using Webdriver sampler with JavaScript. Is it possible to use external code in a sampler? I have many samplers which use almost same code. I want to write this code in an external file and call the required methods (with appropriate arguments) in multiple samplers. If it is not possible then is there a way to call a sampler from within another sampler?

Comment: Question is too broad: try to provide a more specific example.

Comment: I don't think marking questions for closing when you don't have enough qualification to understand them is correct way of using SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example if you have `foo.js` file in JMeter's "bin" folder with the following [function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_function.asp) defined

```
    function hello() {
        WDS.log.info('Hello there')
    }
```

You can just call [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Shell#load.28.5Bfilename.2C_....5D.29) directive in your [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/) code in order to import the aforementioned `foo.js` file lile:

```
load('foo.js')
```

Full code:

```
load('foo.js') // import external file
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
hello()  // call external function
WDS.browser.get('http://jmeter-plugins.org')
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter WebDriver Sampler Load External File]

More information: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered)